# ajax response and class definitions

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I am running an ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",  
    url: "tester2.php",
    data: "username="+username+"&password="+password+"&sessionId="+sessionId,
    success: function(result){
        if (result.length > 0){
            $('#waiting').empty();
            $('#newLine').append(result);
        }
    }
});
```

result equals either

```
 <li class='dog'>Dog</li>
```

or

```
 <li class='cat'>Cat</li>
```

ajax appends this li to the div.

```
  <div id='newLine'></div>
```

the result is just a new line in the newline div.  i have a css with attributes for cat or dog (changing font color) and that has no affect on font color. any thoughts?

this works in firefox as expected, not in chrome...

Comment: Use something like FireBug to verify that you are actually sending back what you expect.  I think it's likely result is <div id='newLine'></div>.

Comment: Could you give us fiddle link?

Comment: it seems that you are returning a space from the server in the worst case => length is not 0

Comment: from firebug response:
<li class='cat'>cat</li>

Comment: can you log the value using `console.log(result);` on chrome ?

Answer (score 0):

[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/housecarl/5ramu/1)

change the request to GET on php file,

acess `tester2.php?username=username&password=password&sessionId=sessionId (insert true vars)`
and see the output. Copy the text and place on fiddle above. check if the problem persists

HTML

```
<div id='newLine'></div>
<button>click</button>
```

JS

```
$('button').click(function(){
$('#newLine').append("<li class='dog'>Dog</li>");
});
```

CSS

```
#newLine .dog 
{
     color:#F00;
}
```